# Parent pane should get resized to outer bounds of rotated child pane

Tags: java, layout, javafx, pane

I want to get a pane resized to a rotated child pane.

Code:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane p1 = new Pane();
        p1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CYAN, null, null)));
        p1.setPrefSize(100, 100);
        p1.setMinSize(100, 100);
        p1.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        p1.setRotate(45);

        Pane p2 = new Pane(p1);
        p2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null)));
        p2.setLayoutX(150);
        p2.setLayoutY(150);

        Group root = new Group(p2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Pane Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(400);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I want to get the parent pane to cover the area obstructed by the child entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by putting Pane p1 into a group and put the group into a borderpane instead of Pane p2 with Position Center. Maybe not the best solution because I am using an extra node, but it works.

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane p1 = new Pane();
        p1.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CYAN, null, null)));
        p1.setPrefSize(100, 100);
        p1.setMinSize(100, 100);
        p1.setMaxSize(100, 100);
        p1.setRotate(45);

        Group g = new Group(p1);

        BorderPane.setAlignment(g, Pos.CENTER);

        BorderPane p2 = new BorderPane(g);

        p2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null)));
        p2.setLayoutX(150);
        p2.setLayoutY(150);

        Group root = new Group(p2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("Pane Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(400);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();


        p1.setRotate(20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```